# IOS MPMoviePlayerViewController Loading endlessly

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-player

I'm working on a IOS App (With Storyoard). I have a ViewController:

```
//movieViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface movieViewController : UIViewController {

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;
-(void) playMovie;

@end


//movieViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self playMovie];
}

-(void)playMovie
{
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie"
                                                      ofType:@"mov"];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL
                                                     fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
```

When I run I see my viewController with a "Loading..." that takes forever.
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you wait till viewDidAppear call before invoking [self playMovie]?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `-prepareToPlay` and/or `-play`. Per [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s documentation:

> Starting in iOS 5.0, in order to facilitate finer-grained playback control, a new movie player is not automatically prepared to play.

Comment: You are mixing up MPMoviePlayerController and MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerViewController has a `moviePlayer` property that is a MPMoviePlayerController object.

Comment: That is true indeed but there is no need to access that property for achieving what the OP asked for. MPMoviePlayerViewController does that out of the box.

Comment: Where is that behavior documented? To the best of my knowledge, that is not the case.

Comment: Calling up both `prepareToPlay` and `play` did not work. Still it hits the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)startVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *video = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:video];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 180);

    controller.moviePlayer.view.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    [controller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [controller.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Can you add some text to explain your solution, please?